# Understanding Solana Wallet connection to Wallet Adapter

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, walletprovider

I'm trying to build a dApp embedded wallet that can interface with the Solana Wallet Adapter. I am looking at the Wallet Standard and I'm wondering if this could be used to build a dApp embedded wallet that exists on the actual site itself (not a browser extension). I'd also need it to auto-connect and feed the wallet adapter, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Anything which has access to the JavaScript context in which the dApp runs can implement the Wallet Standard and register as a `@solana/wallet-adapter` compatible wallet.

See [`solanaWallet.ts`](https://github.com/wallet-standard/wallet-standard/blob/master/packages/example/wallets/src/solanaWallet.ts) for an example of how to build a Wallet Standard wallet, and [this](https://github.com/wallet-standard/wallet-standard/blob/ce280f05f6eb16d0e77939827e0b7fa294460e1f/packages/example/wallets/src/window.ts#L8-L9) for an example of how to register it.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks, in terms of registering the wallet, is that the same as connecting or is that separate? I need the wallet to be able to autoconnect to the dApp without having ever being connected in the first place.

Comment: It's separate. ‘Registering’ means to add it to the Wallet Standard registry so that apps can _discover_ which wallets they can connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same hassle of trying to decode the examples and documented the process [in this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/8105/3983).